# Iterating through List<interface> Items

Tags: c#, list, interface, iteration

I cant figure out why I cant iterate through a list by the class I have interfaced.

eg.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Chicken:IAnimal
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog:IAnimal
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var AnimalList = new List<IAnimal>();

        var Chicken1= new Chicken() { Name = "Chicken" }; 
        var Dog1= new Dog() { Name = "Dog" };

        AnimalList.Add(Dog1);
        AnimalList.Add(Chicken1);

        foreach (Dog obj in AnimalList)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(obj.Name); 
        }
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong, is there a better angle to approach this sort of scenario.

Comment: You really haven't explained what is going wrong with this code.

Comment: I might be reading into your question a bit, but if you're trying to *only* hit the Dog objects in the loop, then filter it. `foreach (Dog obj in AnimalList.OfType<Dog>())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined your list so that it contains elements of `IAnimal`.

```
var AnimalList = new List<IAnimal>();
```

Then in your loop you're specifying the element as `Dog`. Now while `Dog` does implement `IAnimal` it's not the only type that does. So if the list contains a type other than `Dog` then your loop fails.

So you have two approaches to fix this.

One is you change your loop to be like this:

```
foreach (IAnimal obj in AnimalList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name); 
}
```

If you do that your code works fine and outputs the name of the dog and chicken.

However, if you only wish to return the `Dog` instances you can filter the list. You'd do that like this:

```
foreach (Dog obj in AnimalList.OfType<Dog>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name); 
}
```

Now it only results in outputting the dog name.

Answer (score 2):

Each `Dog` *is an* `IAnimal`, but not each `IAnimal` *is a* `Dog`. Especially not `Chicken`: it's definitely not a `Dog`. That is why this loop is going to run into an exception when it reaches `Chicken`:

```
foreach (Dog obj in AnimalList) {
    ...
}
```

However, if you do it like this

```
foreach (IAnimal obj in AnimalList) {
    ...
}
```

or an equivalent

```
foreach (var obj in AnimalList) {
    ...
}
```

the code is going to compile and run correctly.